# Permutation of summation indexex

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Is it permissible to switch indexes in summation i.e. rewrite sum somewhere in equation from $\sum_{k=0}^{n} a^{k}b^{n-k}$ to $\sum_{k=0}^{n} a^{n-k}b^{k}$? Results of both sums are equal, so I *guess* that it might be right.

Comment: In finite sums you can rearrange the terms because addition is commutative so your transformation is absolutely valid.

Comment: @Solomonoff'sSecret, okay thanks! It will simplify proving binomial theorem **a lot**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can think of it this way:

$$\begin{align*}
\{a^kb^{n-k}:0\le k\le n\}&=\{a^kb^\ell:k,\ell\ge\text{ and }k+\ell=n\}\\
&=\{a^{n-k}b^k:0\le k\le n\}\;,
\end{align*}$$

so the sums of the members of these sets are the same.

When you’re actually manipulating summations it’s sometimes helpful to make actual substitutions. Here you could set $\ell=n-k$. As $k$ runs from $0$ to $n$, $\ell$ clearly runs from $n$ down to $0$, covering the same values in the opposite order, and we also have $k=n-\ell$, so

$$\sum_{k=0}^na^kb^{n-k}=\sum_{\ell=0}^na^{n-\ell}b^\ell\;;$$

now just rename the index variable back to $k$ on the righthand side, since it’s a dummy variable anyway, and you have the desired equality. In this case it’s probably overkill, but in more complicated examples it can be quite helpful.